# How do I add multiple values from a dictionary to a PySpark Dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, dictionary, pyspark

I cannot create the entire PySpark Dataframe that I need. My current dictionary is in this format:

```
d = {0:   
{'Key Features': ['Obese', 'Exercise']},  
'Properties': {'Balding': True, 'Tall': False, 'Obese': True, 'Exercise': False}},  
1:  
{'Key Features': [None]},  
'Properties': {'Balding': True, 'Tall': False, 'Obese': False, 'Exercise': True}},  
...}
```

I want to create a dataframe in this format:

```
+---------+------+-------+----------+---------------------+  
|'Balding'|'Tall'|'Obese'|'Exercise'|       'Key Features'|  
+---------+------+-------+----------+---------------------+  
|     true| false|  false|     false|['Obese', 'Exercise']|  
+---------+------+-------+----------+---------------------+  
|     true| false|  false|      true|               [None]|  
+---------+------+-------+----------+---------------------+
```

I was able to create a DataFrame for the 'Properties' with this code:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([d[i]['Properties'] for i in d]).show()
```

Which outputs this dataframe:

```
+---------+------+-------+----------+
|'Balding'|'Tall'|'Obese'|'Exercise'|
+---------+------+-------+----------+
|     true| false|  false|     false|
+---------+------+-------+----------+
|     true| false|  false|      true|
+---------+------+-------+----------+
```

I have tried to add a column like this and it failed:

```
df.withColumn('Key Features', array(lit([d[i]['Key Features'] for i in d])
```

But it simply fails and does not add the list as a column.
And I tried to create a DataFrame like this and it also did not work:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([d[i]['Key Features'] for i in d]).show()
```

Outputting:
Input row doesn't have expected number of values required by the schema. 4 fields are required while 1 values was provided.
How would I go about adding the 'Key Features' as a column with the list contained in the dictionary either by adding it at the start of the createDataFrame or using withColumn?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your example input `d` is a bit malformed since it puts `'Properties'` at the same level as `0` and `1`, and there are multiple `'Properties'` keys at the top level as a result. Given how you index into `d`, I'm going to assume `d` looks like this. Let me know if my assumptions are wrong and I will try to correct the answer.

```py
d = {
    0: {
        'Key Features': ['Obese', 'Exercise'],
        'Properties': {'Balding': True, 'Tall': False, 'Obese': True, 'Exercise': False},
    },
    1: {
        'Key Features': [None],
        'Properties': {'Balding': True, 'Tall': False, 'Obese': False, 'Exercise': True},
    },
}
```

You can create the dataframe you want using this.

```py
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        {"Key Features": v["Key Features"], **v["Properties"]}
        for v in d.values()
    ]
)
df.show()
+-------+--------+-----------------+-----+-----+
|Balding|Exercise|     Key Features|Obese| Tall|
+-------+--------+-----------------+-----+-----+
|   true|   false|[Obese, Exercise]| true|false|
|   true|    true|           [null]|false|false|
+-------+--------+-----------------+-----+-----+
```